# How to get new release path in Capistrano 3?

Tags: capistrano, roots-sage

Trying to use Capistrano 3 to deploy a project and have run into an issue. In one of my tasks I'm trying to change directories and then run composer install.

For the life of me I can't get it to `cd` into the proper folder.

Right now if I do

```
set :theme_path, "#{release_path}/web/app/themes/sage"
append :linked_dirs, "web/app/uploads"
append :linked_files, ".env"
set :keep_releases, 3

namespace :deploy do

desc "Build"
after :updated, :build do
    on roles(:app) do
        within release_path do
            execute :composer, "install --no-dev --quiet"
            execute :cd, "#{fetch(:theme_path)}; composer install --no-dev --quiet"
        end
    end
  end

end
```

It's for some reason running it in the previous release. Doing a `pwd` instead of the `composer install` shows that it is inside /current/ and not in the new /release/ directory. So it runs my composer install in current, and then does all the symlinking, so I end up with it always running composer in the previous deploy, so my current deploy never works.

So if `release_path` is /current/ and not the release currently being deployed... how do I get that path? Or how should I go about running `composer install` in two places?

Answer (score 2):

The `within` syntax is how you tell Capistrano where to `execute` a command. I am not sure why this isn't working for you. I've copied and pasted your example into one of my apps at it works fine:

```
namespace :deploy do
  after :updated, :build do
    on roles(:app) do
      within release_path do
        puts capture("pwd")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I run `cap production deploy` I see the `pwd` I expect in the output:

```
/home/deployer/apps/[REDACTED]/releases/20180405162938
```

You definitely should not be using `execute :cd`. Use `within` instead. So for example, if you need to do two executions, one in `release_path` and another in `:theme_path`, then I would do the following:

```
within release_path do
  execute :composer, "install --no-dev --quiet"
end

within fetch(:theme_path) do
  execute :composer, "install --no-dev --quiet"
end
```